# F# Function where x is divisible by 2 or 3 but not 5

Tags: f#

```
I have a function that determines whether a value is divisible by 2 or 3, but **NOT** 5:

let ttnf x =  
    if (x % 2 = 0) || (x % 3 = 0) && not(x % 5 = 0) then true 
        else 
            false
```

I'm getting a weird response from Visual Studio 2015 in the interactive panel.
I execute the above code in the F# interactive panel then enter say...

```
ttnf 15
```

Hit enter, nothing...
hit alt + enter then it returns it on the second time.
Any idea why it isn't returning true/false from entering:

```
ttnf 15
```

The first time?

Thanks.

Comment: Seems, you have many beginner question. I think you might want to join the FSSF. There is an active channel for helping newbies. Just sign up on the website and after a while you'll get an invite. If you have any questions, just give me a ping in [F# chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51909/f).

Comment: `&&` has higher precedence than `||`, so add parentheses: `let ttnf x = (x % 2 = 0 || x % 3 = 0) && x % 5 <> 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ildjarn commented about the error in your code, but about F# interactive's behavior: when you type code directly into fsi, you need to terminate each declaration with `;;` to tell fsi to interpret it, otherwise it will just wait for you to continue your input (as you experienced). So:

```
> let ttnf x =  
    if (x % 2 = 0 || x % 3 = 0) && not(x % 5 = 0) then true 
        else 
            false;;

val ttnf : x:int -> bool

> ttnf 15;;

val it : bool = false

>
```

Comment: you could have added the "other (unnamed) part" of @ildjarn comment ; if you have a pattern like `if cond then true else false` ; meaning if `cond` is `true` return `true` otherwise (if `cond` is `false`) return `false` ; you can directly return `cond` as a truth value.